# While loop and calling a function in python

Tags: python, while-loop

```py
def func(val):

    num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    while(num!=val):
        if num < val:
            print ("Too low!")
            return -1
            num = int(input("Try again: "))
        elif num > val:
            print ("Too high!")
            return 1
            num = int(input("Try again: "))
        else:
            print ("Got it!!!")
            break
            return 0
        print
    func(20)
```

With this code, it does not loop. It asks me what my number is and lets me know if it's right or not, but it does not re-ask me to input a new number. Did I call the function in the incorrect place? Or is it my condition in my while loop that is incorrect?

Comment: `return` exits the function. It should only be in the `else` case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def func(val):
  while True:
      num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
      if num < val:
          print ("Too low!")
      elif num > val:
          print ("Too high!")
      else:
          print("Got it")
          break
func(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It will never ask you the number again, because you are returning a value in every condition before asking for a number. So it gets out of the loop at the very first time.


# the function can be like this

def func(val):
  while True:
      num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
      if num < val:
          print ("Too low!")
      elif num > val:
          print ("Too high!")
      else:
          print("Got it")
          break
func(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put "num" row into the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, break line exits loop, in your case when the loop is exited, the function is exited too. `return -1` statement exits function, so you shouldn`t use it too if you want to get user's input no matter what user inputs first time and so on.
The correct code will look like this.

```py
def func(val): 
    num = int(input("Enter a number:")) 
    while(num!=val): 
        if num < val: 
            print ("Too low!") 
            num = int(input("Try again: ")) 
        elif num > val: 
            print ("Too high!") 
            num = int(input("Try again: ")) 
        else: 
            print ("Got it!!!") 
            return 0 
func(20)
```

P.S. Identation is very important in Python, so forat your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

2nd last line print is unusable,

here is correct code :

```
def func(val):
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
while(num!=val):
    if num < val:
       print ("Too low!")
       return -1
       num = int(input("Try again: "))
    elif num > val:
       print ("Too high!")
       return 1
       num = int(input("Try again: "))
    else:
       print ("Got it!!!")
       break
       return 0

func(20)
```